# Do I need to bargain with my credit card customer service for better offers?

Tags: credit-card

I am very new with credit card stuffs. I started with a BOA secure credit card with a credit limit of $300. I always pay off my balance in full each month and never go beyond my credit limit. I usually try to keep my credit utilization below 20%, only once it was %60.

I expected access to higher credit line after several months, but now BOA has offered only $100 credit line increase, so a total combined credit line of $400.

I know that my credit score affect the credit line, but I want to know if after all, my current credit card issuer consider the fact that I am only with them so they do not need to necessarily provide me a better offer? I mean if I had another option (another credit card), doe BOA would done the same (only increasing $100 over after several months)?

Do I need to bargain with BOA customer service for higher credit line?

Comment: What would be the harm? The worst they can say is no, then you are no worse off than you are now.

Comment: I've had success in the past with getting a credit limit raised just by asking, so it's worth a shot. I wouldn't really call it "bargaining".  They do know there are other credit card issuers out there, and if they can't give you a product that works for you, you will look for someone else who will.  On a side note, you might also consider trying to get an unsecured card.

Comment: @NateEldredge In fact to ask for a credit line increase in BOA, I should apply again! As they have only increased my credit line by $100, so my application could be denied and as you know it can negatively affect my score.

Comment: I'm responding to your follow-up question/comment above. I agree with everything Mark said. For a second card, as long as you are diligent about paying off your balance every month, you have the luxury of selecting based on awards and the credit limit offered. 1.5% cash back is pretty good, and Visa and MC are a bit more widely accepted. Discover has those rotating 5% deals, and often in useful categories, but at the risk of tempting you to spend money when you otherwise wouldn't. Discover is widely accepted, but not as ubiquitous as Visa/MC. So you could go either way, but the CapitalOne offe

Comment: FYI: Usually you cannot get multiple credit line increases (on the same card) within a 6 month period, even if the bank sends you a specifically targeted credit line increase offer a couple months after you accepted their last specifically targeted credit line increase offer.

Answer (score 2):

You should have two cards minimum.  Banks for no reason could close your account and then you credit score will get hammered.

If I were you I would get an account at CreditKarma.com.  They are a free monitoring site, which is free because they give show you credit card ads that are relevant for your credit score.

Plan B or maybe Plan A would be to find a credit union and get another card.
You never know BOA might just pull your card away from you, its rare but it does happen.

Comment: I have currently two offers in my mailbox 1) Quicksilver from CapitalOne: No annual fee, 0% intro APR, 24.9% APR after Aug 2015 and 1.5% cash back. 2) Discover: 0% intro Apr for 14 month, 18.99% after that,5% cash back on categories that changes and 1% cash back on all other purchases. Which one, do you think, is better?

Comment: I do Like the Discover cash back I have that one right now its 5% back on online shopping which is going to be a free $75 for me.  If you are going to travel abroad then Capital One has no junk fees when using in other countries and discover just plain will not be accepted.  For me I am at a point in my life were I will never have a balance so I don't ever look at APR.